# Heroku MySQL accents problem

Tags: mysql, heroku

Is there any way to change the Heroku's MySQL ruby gem's version?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Heroku doesn't use MySQL as their database engine.

They use PostgreSQL.

Here's a snippet from their FAQ:

> What database does Heroku use?
>
> Our
>   shared database uses PostgreSQL 8.3.
>   Our dedicated database uses PostgreSQL
>   9.
>
> Source: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 0):

If using rails 2.3.* then you can specify the gem version you need in the .gems file.

```
mysql --version x.x.x
```

If using rails 3 then use the Gemfile.

Comment: this is rails 2.x way of doing things - put `gem 'mysql'` inside Gemfile if you're on rails 3

Comment: Thanks. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

according to the list of [installed gems](http://installed-gems.heroku.com/) they are at version 2.7.

If you are on rails3, then just stick `gem 'mysql'` in your Gemfile.

Why are you using mysql gem? Is it for the Amazon RDS add-on or something?

Comment: Just a side note. Heroku will work with any mysql host not just Amazon RDS. Heroku ignores database.yml so you have to define the host in the DATABASE_URL config key.